# The iframe in frameset onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have frameset included in the iframe onload.

Iframe Trying to onload an iframe...
but, this code is be not fully loaded.

A.jsp is loaded. but frame in frameset is not loaded.

```
<iframe id = "testFrm" src = "A.jsp"></iframe>
```

Script

```
document.getElementById('testFrm').onload = function(){
   console.log('test');
}
```

A.jsp

```
<frameset>
 <frame src = "a.jsp"></frame>
 <frame src = "b.jsp"></frame>
</frameset>
```

Is there a way to load the entire page of the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a simple counter to measure how many frames have loaded?

```
// <frame> elements
var frames = document.querySelectorAll("#my-frameset frame");

// total frames loaded - initially 0
var framesLoaded = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    frames[i].onload = function() {
        framesLoaded++;

        if (framesLoaded === frames.length) {
            // all frames loaded
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But, Chorme is not working... IE/Edge/FF is working. Why!?